# How to add an accordion inside a leafletjs popup marker?

Tags: leaflet

I would like to include a collapsible button/accordion inside a leaflet pop-up marker. I have added a button, +css, +js, but It is always closed despite clicking it. Has anyone experienced this issue. Please help me.

The Popup Tooltip

```
function processPcodemarker(json,lyr){
            var att = json.properties;
            if (att.type=='Recording'){
            lyr.bindPopup("<div id='details'><img width='100' class='rounded' src='data/hamish.jpg' alt='avatar'> <h2 float='top-right'>"+att.title+"</h2><div class='bingo'><button id='btnT' class='collapsible'>Red Ridding</button><div id='btnSee' class='content'>"+att.mp3+"</div></div><h5>Date</h5>"+att.date+"<h5>Location</h5>"+att.location+"<br> <h5>Observation</h5>"+att.observation+" <h5>Type</h5>"+att.type+"<button type='button' class='badge badge-light badge-color'>Amen</button></div><button id='accordion'class='accordion active'>Section 1</button><div id='panelin' class='panel'><p>Lorem ipsum...</p></div>").openPopup().addTo(mymap);
```

The CSS

```
.accordion {
          background-color: #eee;
          color: #444;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 18px;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: left;
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          transition: 0.4s;
        }

        /* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
        .active, .accordion:hover {
          background-color: #ccc;
        }

        /* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
        .panel {
              padding: 30 18px;
              display: none;
              background-color: white;
              max-height: 10;
              overflow: hidden;
              transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
        }
```

JavaScript

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
                var i;

                for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                    } else {
                      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
                    }
                  });
                }
```

The JavaScript has been copied from W3schools, but cannot implement inside a leaflet marker popup. Please assist

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is was through a similar question relating to the link below. I further expanded the information to create a pop up with an accordion with a working click event.

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698975/click-link-inside-leaflet-popup-and-do-javascript`

This

````
                    var container = $('<div />');
                    container.on('click', '.smallPolygonLink', function(){
                        this.classList.toggle('is-open');
                        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                        if (content.style.maxHeight){
                            // accordion is open, we need to close it
                            content.style.maxHeight = null;
                        }else{
                            //accordion is closed
                            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                        }
                    });
                    container.html("<button class='smallPolygonLink'>Media 2</button><div class='smallPolygonLink-content'><p> Cheppar Limited, Founded in April 2017</p></div>");

                    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap).bindPopup(container[0]);
                }); ```

Kindly add CSS

```button.smallPolygonLink{
    width:100%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}

button.smallPolygonLink::after{
    content: '\f103';
    font-family: "fontawesome";
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
}

button.smallPolygonLink.is-open::after {
    content:"\f102";
}

button.smallPolygonLink:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.smallPolygonLink-content {
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid whitesmoke;
    border-right: 1px solid whitesmoke;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}```
````